# Red bar issue when application goes in background(Using AVCaptureSession) and AVCamPreviewLayer jerk

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios-camera, avcam

I developed a custom camera functionality using Apple's sample code **AVCAM** and in my application the **background modes** are enabled which is causing red bar issue.

I create AVCaptureSession and then add inputs(.Video,.Audio) and outputs in session.

Below is code to add audio input in session

```
var audioDeviceInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput!

guard let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.audio) else { return }

    do {
        audioDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)
    } catch let error {
        audioDeviceInput = nil
        NSLog("Could not create audio device input: \(error)")
    }

self.session.addInput(audioDeviceInput)
```

Now when user presses home button, the red bar flashes on iPhone screen for milliseconds and then disappear(indicating the mic is being used) and i want to avoid this red bar.

After doing some R&D i came to know this is happening because of audio input added in session (the code of adding audio input is mention above)

What i have done so far is? 
To resolve this issue, I only adding audio input when user starts recording video and remove audio input when user stops video. This actually resolved the red bar problem but this happens to cause **jerk** in preview which is really irritating. Now, i want to resolve this UI jerk but doesn't know how to do this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Create separate session for audio and just add the audio session while capturing video.This will solve the problem